# How to make a program that see if the entered word equals to A?

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm learning Java on netbeans so I looked for some exercises.
I was trying to complete this exercise : write a java program that prompt user to enter a word and check if this word starts with letter 'A'.

So I wrote this code :

```
package testone;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestOne {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        String strA = "A";
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter a word : ");
        String userWord = s.next();
        char firstLetter = userWord.charAt(0);

        if (strA.equals(firstLetter)) {

            System.out.println("Your word starts with letter A ");

        }else {

            System.out.println("Your word doesn't start with letter A ");

        }


    }

}
```

but It didn't work probably, any ideas ?

Comment: Why are you comparing a `String` and a `char`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are comparing a `String` with a `char` here: `if (strA.equals(firstLetter)) {`. That's like checking if an apple is equal to a pear; it will always be false.

Instead, simply check if the input starts with A:

```
if (userWord.startsWith("A")) {
```

See [Java - String - startsWith](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith(java.lang.String)) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

According to [the doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29):

> `public boolean equals(Object anObject)`
>
> Compares this string to the specified object. The result is true if
>   and only if the argument is not null and is a String object that
>   represents the same sequence of characters as this object.

You are call ing this method with a parameter of type `char`, which will be boxed into a `Character` instance, which does not extend `String`. The result will always be `false`.

Use `userWord.startsWith("A")` instead, or `userWord.charAt(0) == 'A'`...

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with that  `userWord.startsWith("A")`

Comment: This function return false if input string does not start with A. I have tested it.

Answer (score 0):

You cant directly compare char and String. Besides what others have given as solution, you can use the `String.valueOf(...)` function and then you'll be able to compare String and char.

```
package testone;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestOne {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    String strA = "A";
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter a word : ");
    String userWord = s.next();
    char firstLetter = userWord.charAt(0);
if (strA.equals(String.valueOf(firstLetter))) {  //Try this

    System.out.println("Your word starts with letter A ");

}else {

    System.out.println("Your word doesn't start with letter A ");

}


}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try the method `yourstring.indexOf('A')`, it returns an `int`, if its 0 so you found "A" at the first position , otherwise no .
Syntax

```
if(yourstring.indexOf('A') == 0 ){
    //do something .....
}
```